# Is it OK to say "functionality wise and productivity wise"

Tags: expressions

We tell a customer about recent changes in our software. Is it OK to say "These changes are very important functionality wise and productivity wise for you"?

Answer (score 4):

“-wise” is a suffix or modifier that changes a noun into an adjective or adverb; it should generally be typeset with a hyphen:

> …functionality-wise and productivity-wise…

Or, if it’s a very common compound, then as a compound word:

> …lengthwise and widthwise…

(The most common words with a “-wise” suffix typically refer to the *dimensions* or *extents* of a thing: “lengthwise”, “longwise”, “widthwise”, “breadthwise”, “slantwise”, “piecewise”, “stepwise”, “otherwise”, “leastwise”, “edgewise”.)

The “-wise” suffix is fairly common in speech, but in writing it’s less common; when writing, it’s more common to change a phrase such as this into something like the following, using prepositions like “in terms of”, and “as for” or “regarding”:

> These changes are very important for you *in terms of* functionality and productivity.
>
> These changes are very important for you *regarding* functionality and productivity.

Answer (score 0):

Is it OK? If you want to make a good impression on your potential customers, I suggest you avoid such words. They are almost meaningless without a lot of further explanation. To some ears, mine, for instance, they hint that the person speaking does not really know what they are talking about. They are waffle. "Functionality-wise" in particular can mean anything. It would be better to say specifically what your improved software can now do, and why it will bring benefits to anyone who uses it.